# Breakpoint will not currently be hit. No executable code associated with this line

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, class, debugging

I have a class in a .h file:

```
class Blah
{
public:
    Blah(){}
    virtual ~Blah(){}

    void WriteMessage( bool MessageReceived )
    {
        if(MessageReceived)
        {
            cout << "Message Recieved\n";
        }
    }
};
```

I was trying to figure out why my code isn't working, so I set a breakpoint on the conditional inside the `WriteMessage()` funcition, but as soon as I started running the project in debug mode the breakpoint faded out and the tooltip for it said:

> Breakpoint will not currently be hit.
>   No executable code associated with this line.

I have no idea why this is happening, because all of my other member functions for other classes work just fine when implemented in the .h file.  What is causing this?

**Edit:** Okay as requested, here's a stripped down version of the real code I'm working with:

**VimbaBridgeAPI.h** (header file for .dll)

```
#pragma once

#ifdef VIMBABRIDGEAPI_EXPORTS
#define VIMBABRIDGEAPI_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define VIMBABRIDGEAPI_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#include "AlCamIncludes.h"
#include "VimbaSystem.h"

////////////////////////////////////////////
//  Global Variables ///////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////
extern HBITMAP hbit;
extern CEdit* global_filenamehandle;

////////////////////////////////////////////
//  Global Flags ///////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////
extern bool imageReady;
extern bool take_picture;

using namespace AVT::VmbAPI;

VIMBABRIDGEAPI_API void BridgedGetImage(FramePtr framepoint, VmbUchar_t** imgDat);

VIMBABRIDGEAPI_API HBITMAP ExternalFrameRecieved( const FramePtr pFrame );

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////  MyObserver class   ///////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class VIMBABRIDGEAPI_API MyObserver : public IFrameObserver
{
private:
    MyObserver( MyObserver& );

    MyObserver& operator=( const MyObserver& );

    //class member variables
    //BITMAPINFO*             pbmi;
    CEdit*                  m_filenameedit;

public:

    MyObserver(CameraPtr pCamera) : IFrameObserver(pCamera) {}
    virtual ~MyObserver() {}

    void FrameReceived ( const FramePtr pFrame );
};
```

**NOTE:** IFrameObserver is not written by me, but the FrameReceived function is a pure virtual declared in the IFrameObserver class.  Their documentation says that FrameRecieved gets called by their API whenever a frame comes in, and I had to implement the function.  I have tested this functions and it works, but only when defined outside the class (inside I get the error I'm getting now)

**VimbaBridgeAPI.cpp** (code hidden from user)

```
void FrameRecieved( const FramePtr pFrame )
{
    DbgMsg(L"Frame Received\n");

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////////  Setup Bitmap  ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //// FILEHEADER ////
    BITMAPFILEHEADER* bf = new BITMAPFILEHEADER;
    bf->bfType = 0x4d42;
    bf->bfSize = 6054400 + 54 + sizeof(BITMAPINFO);
    bf->bfOffBits = 54;

    //// INFOHEADER ////
    BITMAPINFOHEADER* bih = new BITMAPINFOHEADER;
    bih->biSize = 40;
    bih->biWidth = 2752;
    bih->biHeight = -2200;
    bih->biPlanes = 1;
    bih->biBitCount = 32;
    bih->biCompression = 0;
    //bi->biSizeImage = 6054400; //not required
    bih->biXPelsPerMeter = 2835;
    bih->biYPelsPerMeter = 2835;
    bih->biClrUsed = 0;
    bih->biClrImportant = 0;

    //// INFO ////
    BITMAPINFO* pbmi = (BITMAPINFO*)alloca( sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + sizeof(RGBQUAD)*256);
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof (pbmi->bmiHeader);
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biWidth = 2752;
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biHeight = -2200;
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biBitCount = 8;
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biSizeImage = 0;
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 14173;
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 14173;
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;

    //create grayscale color palette
    for(int i=0; i<256; i++)
    {
        pbmi->bmiColors[i].rgbRed = BYTE(i);
        pbmi->bmiColors[i].rgbGreen = BYTE(i);
        pbmi->bmiColors[i].rgbBlue = BYTE(i);
        pbmi->bmiColors[i].rgbReserved = BYTE(0);
    }

    //// IMAGE DATA ////
    VmbUchar_t* imageData = NULL;
    BridgedGetImage(pFrame, &imageData);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////// Create image that's printed to dialog box /////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    HDC hdc = ::GetDC(NULL);  
    hbit = CreateDIBitmap(hdc, bih, CBM_INIT, imageData, pbmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    //clean up
    DeleteObject(bf);
    DeleteObject(bih);
    DeleteObject(hdc);
}
```

Comment: Does your code ever call `Blah::WriteMessage`?

Comment: You probably haven't associated your `WriteMessage` with anything that is on execution path, so the compiler throws out this code. Simply said, this code is never executed

Comment: are you maybe debugging the release version or an outdated build?

Comment: 1) Yes. Many times. 2) What exactly do you mean? 3)No.

Comment: Well, if you claim it's being executed, put a breakpoint on one of the calling lines and step through from there.

Comment: Did the path of "Debug" change?

Comment: hmm, is it a real code that you try to debug or an illustratio?

Comment: @icepack The program gets to the line where it calls WriteMessage, and then when I hit F10, it "executes" it and it seems like it worked, but if I use F11 to try to step in, it says that the source file has changed since I last built it.  I reloaded it and it just keeps giving that error.

Comment: `WriteMessage` being inline, if you always call `WriteMessage (false)` compiler will optimize it out. May be that's the problem?

Comment: please check the timestamp on your source file?

Comment: Might be related to inlining. Try to move the function body out of the header file

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic it is an illustratio, the code I'm using contains lots of libraries and .h files provided by different companies.  I can still try to show the relevant parts of the code

Comment: @xcdemon05, try full rebuild?

Comment: @aleguna actually, this might be true even if it's not inline

Comment: @aleguna I've tried it, but to no avail

Comment: I thought so, please at least show the real `WriteMessage` method. I am quite sure that this is not exactly the same and you might have missed some detail. However, since you have 'file changed' message, I would still check the timestamps. If you reload the file it changes nothing, as it is your .exe that is outdated

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic okay I will edit my post now

Comment: Is this code a part of your .exe or a part of a dll being loaded by the .exe? if latter, maybe you are not loading the version you expected.

Comment: Hmm, the question asks about BP not being hit, while it seems that the real problem is that the function doesn't get called. For the first question, you need to show where in the real function was the BP location. For the function not being called, are you sure that your override has exactly the same signature (maybe missed a `&` or something) - most likely it does as compiler would complain since base class is pure. Is your observer registered at all? If your function doesn't get called, and the base class has a pure virtual declaration, then what function does get called?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would suggest you firstly **Delete the output files** : Physically delete all generated DLLs, PDBs and EXEs. Then compile (rebuild) again to generate the files. Sometimes Visual Studio can "get lost" and "forget" to overwrite the output files when you build your solution.

This can happen for a few other reasons:

- The code the debugger is using is different from the code that the application is running
- The pdb file that the debugger is using is different from the code that the application is running
- The code the application is running has been optimized and debug information has been stripped out.
- The code in which you have breakpoints on hasn't been loaded into the process yet

Comment: Looking closer at the symptoms, I think I may be running into "The code the debugger is using is different from the code that the application is running".  I cannot set breakpoints in certain functions, yet they still seem to run okay without breakpoints.  Also, changing the functions are not changing the way my program runs.  Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Use Process Monitor (downloadable from Microsoft) to check which executable you're actually debugging, and compare it to which executable is being built.

Comment: I tried to step into one of the functions that I am unable to set breakpoints inside of, and I got this error message:  http://i.imgur.com/iI8AfpU.png

Comment: I did do this, but it didn't seem to work, so I re-added the breakpoint one line up which seems to have magically put VS back on track. Repositioning the breakpoint seems to have worked for me once before, if I may recall, as this has happened to me in the past. I am using VS2013 Express Web.

Comment: This worked for my web application project in VS 2013. I had to do one additional thing, had to use Internet Explorer as default browser in VS 2013.

Answer (score 8):

I wound up having this issue too, the context of my app was a main app in C# which used unmanaged C++ code in a lower layer that I wanted to step into from the debugger. From the C# project properties I went into the Debug tab and under the Enable Debuggers section checked the "Enable unmanaged code debugging".

[image: C# Project Properties Debug Tab]

Comment: While my issue had nothing to do with C#, I'm upvoting this, because it came the closest to addressing it. 

When running managed(CLR) and unmanaged code in C++, it's important to set the Debugger Type to "Mixed", otherwise it will skip over any unmanaged code.

Comment: I agree with the commenter above (when trying to debug a C++ program, the above property page is not available). Setting debugging to "native" or "auto" does not work, but apparently "Mixed" does. Thanks!

Comment: +1, As Digital_Utopia says, I had to **manually** set my (non-CLR) C++ project to use "mixed" rather than "auto", just to pull in my .lib files.

Comment: +1, Not only did it solve my problem, I have found some one else who's arrow-drawing skills are as bad as mine.

Comment: And in VS2013 it's called "Enable native code debugging". Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 8):

Wanted to mention that I experienced the `"Breakpoint will not be hit..."` error when porting some of my older `MFC (managed--using clr support)` projects into `VS2015`.

What fixed the issue for me was setting this:

`Configuration Properties\Linker\Debugging\Debuggable Assembly`

... to this:

`Yes (/ASSEMBLYDEBUG)`

Answer (score 4):

I also wanted to chime in with my own solution. I had a C++ project loading a dll that consisted of C++/CLR code. Turns out, I had to set the startup project's debugger type to "Mixed". "Auto" wasn't detecting that it needed managed support because the dll was loaded manually after the program started.

Comment: Man, you saved my day! I had exactly same issue and this really helped! Thx a lot for this comment.

Comment: I had the inverse problem - "Auto" picked managed even through most of the code is native.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the answer was:

`Project Properties->C/C++->Optimization`

Set Optimization to : "Disabled (/Od)"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but the accepted solution of cleaning up files didn't work for me. I have my issue resolved and it had to do with my code. Here are the details of my fix, hope it gives some clues to your fix.

What I was doing is overloading `CArchive` `<<` operator for my structure but the code never steps into it. I would set the break point and I got the solid red symbol. As soon as I start debugger the symbol becomes outlined and the warning message on it says:

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. no executable code is associated with this line

My relevant code is below where the break point doesn't break.

```
class Book
{
     friend CArchive& operator << (CArchive& ar, const Book & book )
     {

         ar << book.title;
         ar << "\r\n";
         ar << book.price;
         ar << "\r\n";
     }
}
```

Now there is an obvious problem with this code is that it doesn't have a return statement `return ar` but the compiler never complained. The reason compiler didn't complain was I was using the operator incorrectly (and rather never using it)

```
book *mybook = new Book(...);
ar << mybook;
```

Because mistakenly I am accessing the operator via pointer, my object's `<<` operator was never really invoked and that's why compiler didn't complain either because it was never being used.

So first I fixed the calling code

```
book *mybook = new Book(...);
ar << *mybook;
```

Now the operator overloading method complains about the `return` statement and I fixed that too.

I can now step into the function. So the bottom line was that the break point was not being set because this code was essentially sidelined by compiler (correctly) because it was never  used in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to press `Ctrl+F5` which gives same as the error you received in Visual Studio Code. However, once I just go to `Debug` section and pressed **Green button** which initialises[image] Debugging helped me solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CLion, try adding `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` to your CMake options:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I hit this problem while attempting to debug a Rust project in IntelliJ. It turns out that the problem was that in the `.cargo/config` file, the `rustflags` variable was set to include `--compress-debug-sections=zlib-gabi`. This apparently deprives IntelliJ of information it needs to activate the debugger. Temporarily removing that flag removed the "breakpoint will not currently be hit" message and allowed the debugger to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue after updating my mingw environment.
However my gdb version that I was using was older than the gdb in the newer mingw environment. I changed the location of GDB in my IDE to the newest version and the problem got resolved.

So for anyone having the same issue as me: `Check if you are using the same version of GDB as the version of your build environment/toolchain.`