# VS2015 C debugging issue: Breakpoint will not currently be hit. No executable code is associated with this line

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015

I am writing a C program with **Visual Studio 2015**.

My C executable links to a `.lib` file, **which is built separately from my executable.**

The `.lib` file is also written in C. And it is built with:

**cl.exe** flags:

> /nologo /c /WX /GS- /W4 /Gs32768 /D UNICODE /Od /GL- /Gy /EHs-c- /GR-
>   /GF /Z7 /Gm- /Gw

**link.exe** flags:

> /NOLOGO /LTCG

---

My executable is built with:

**cl.exe** flags:

> /GS- /TC /W4 /Zc:wchar_t Z7 /Gm /O1 /Fd"C:\source\TEST2.pdb"
>   /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "_MBCS" /errorReport:prompt /WX-
>   /Zc:forScope /Gd /MTd /Fa"x64\Debug\" /Fo"C:\source\x64\Debug\"
>   /Fp"x64\TEST2.pch"  /c /WX- /GS- /W4 /Gs32768 /D UNICODE /Od  /GL- /Gy
>   /EHs-c- /GR- /GF /Z7 /Gm- /Gw  /wd4054 /wd4477 /U_DEBUG

**link.exe** flags:

> /OUT:"C:\source\x64\Debug\TEST2.exe" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT
>   /PDB:"C:\source\x64\Debug\TEST2.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib"
>   "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib"
>   "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib"
>   "odbccp32.lib" /DEBUG /MACHINE:X64 /INCREMENTAL:NO
>   /PGD:"C:\source\x64\Debug\TEST2.pgd" /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker'
>   uiAccess='false'"
>   /ManifestFile:"x64\Debug\TEST2.exe.intermediate.manifest"
>   /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /TLBID:1  /NODEFAULTLIB:libc.lib
>   /NODEFAULTLIB:libcmt.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrt.lib
>   /NODEFAULTLIB:libcd.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrtd.lib

---

When I debug through the whole application, I encountered below error for ***some*** breakpoints ***in the lib***.

[image]

So I did some experiment.

In the `.c` file that has above issue, I tried to add break-point pair to the **beginning** curly bracket and **ending** bracket of **all** the C functions within that file.

I noticed that for some functions, the break-point pair ***can be hit***. Like below:

[image]

But then I encountered a function where the break-point at the ending bracket ***cannot be hit***. Like below:

[image]

And **all the subsequent functions** suffer from the same issue.

I checked this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205750/breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-executable-code-associated-with-this-li).

I tried clean rebuild, no use.

I use the `/Z7` so there's no PDB files. *I guess* all debug info are embedded in the lib file.

I had `/Od` so *I guess* the optimization is not in my way.

Then what could be wrong?

Could any one shed some light? Thanks.

Comment: PDB doesn't get embedded in a lib (or other object file). Without a valid PDB, you cannot put breakpoints at the source level. The fact that it allows it at the braces is perhaps due to recognized entry/exit code.

Comment: @Michael Thanks. But for *some* functions in that lib, the breakpoint can work at locations other than the beginning/ending of the body.  At least seemingly.

Comment: @Michael How to generate a PDB file for a lib? And since the lib is statically linked to the executable, can its PDB still be useful?

Comment: The PDB contains only symbols and other stuff needed for debugging. It is not related to static/dynamic linking (all executable formats can have a PDB which is only useful for the debugger, not for running whatsoever). Try the /Zi option.

Comment: @Michael According to MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/958x11bc.aspx): */Z7: Produces an .obj file **containing** full symbolic debugging information for use with the debugger.*

Comment: I just saw it, but tbh I 've never used it. Try /Zi

Comment: @Michael `.lib` just packages a bunch of `obj`s. So I guess the debugging info are there. Anyway, I will have a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(<strike>This is not an answer *yet*</strike>. **This is an answer now**. I post my investigation here so the original post won't be too long.)

### Try 1

I tried to use `/Zi` for my lib. And it produces a `vc140.pdb` file. (btw, the lib file size is much smaller than the `/Z7` situation)

Then I debug my application. I tried to put this `vc140.pdb` file in the symbol file window as below:

[image]

But it didn't work. (This is kind of expected because how could VS2015 know this pdb file is for the statically linked lib, which is just a part of the executable now.)

### Try 2

There are 3 similar scenarios where a break-point cannot be hit.

Scenario 1:

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No executable code of the
>   debugger's target code type is associated with this line.

[image]

Scenario 2:

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No Symbols have been loaded
>   for this document.

[image]

Scenario 3:

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. The source code is different
>   from the original version.

[image]

During the investigation, I was lucky enough to encountered all 3 of them.

To fix 2, check here: http://www.wwwlicious.com/2016/02/28/how-to-load-debug-symbols-during-debugging/

To fix 3, double check that your file is of correct version.

For 1. Based on the its very description, **I believe the debug symbol must have been loaded in 1, which is not the same as 2.** But somehow, the debug symbol info is corrupted somewhere in the middle, which causes break points for some functions are OK while others are BAD.

### Try 3

According to the error description, there can be 2 most likely reasons:

- Conditional Compilation
- Compiler Optimization

I focus on Compiler Optimization for now.

I set `/Od` for `cl.exe` to [disable optimization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/od-disable-debug?view=vs-2017).

I set `/GL-` for `cl.exe` to disable [whole program optimization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/gl-whole-program-optimization?view=vs-2017).

I remove the `/LTCG` to disable [link time code generation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/ltcg-link-time-code-generation?view=vs-2017), which is also a kind of whole-program optimization.

Seems still not work.

### Try 4  --- Issue Solved!!!

(*Finally, my mom's blessing saved the day!*)

**The root cause turns out to be the line ending style!**

Visual Studio keeps prompting me for the C file which contains the unreachable  break points. As below:

[image]

After I normalize the line endings, all break points work fine now!

Below is a previously unreachable break point.

[image]

---

BTW, I really didn't expect that Microsoft Visual Studio sticks to the `CR LF` style so *strictly*.

*Does it hurt to be a little bit more benign/intelligent?*